# Qt - What to use for a text box

Tags: c++, qt, textbox

I'm new to Qt, and just want to ask. What should I use to make a text box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If with `text box` you mean it `one line` then it should be [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html).

Anyway I suggest you to get a look at some [full working samples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html) to learn using all available widgets.

Comment: +1: Check out examples and demos ... also `QTextEdit` if you need a bit more.

Answer (score 33):

`QLineEdit` for textbox

`QTextEdit` for textareas

`QPushButton` for buttons

Here's the complete Qt Widgets API reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-index.html#api-reference

Answer (score 0):

`QLabel` for displaying text or images that the user cannot directly interact with or modify.

`QLineEdit` for single-line text input, allowing users to enter and edit a line of plain text.

`QTextEdit` for multi-line text input, suitable for rich text formatting, including images, hyperlinks, and styled text.

`QPlainTextEdit` for multi-line plain text input, optimized for handling large documents without rich text formatting.

`QPushButton` for a clickable button that can initiate actions or commands.

Example:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QStyleFactory>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QPalette>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Light theme
    QStyle* style = QStyleFactory::create("Fusion");
    QPalette palette = style->standardPalette();
    QApplication::setStyle(style);
    QApplication::setPalette(palette);

    QWidget window;
    window.setWindowTitle("QtTextExample");

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(&window);

    QLabel* label = new QLabel("QLabel: Display text or images.");
    layout->addWidget(label);

    QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit("QLineEdit: Sample input text");
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit);

    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit();
    textEdit->setHtml(
            "<h1>QTextEdit</h1>"
            "<p>This is <b>bold</b>, this is <i>italic</i>, and this is <span style='color: red;'>colored</span> text.</p>"
            "<p>List:</p>"
            "<ul>"
                "<li>Item 1</li>"
                "<li>Item 2</li>"
            "</ul>");
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);

    QPlainTextEdit* plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit("QPlainTextEdit: Enter multi-line plain text here.\nIt's optimized for text editing without rich formatting.");
    layout->addWidget(plainTextEdit);

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("QPushButton: Click me");
    layout->addWidget(button);

    window.show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Result:
[image]